# Why is $product null on modules/productcomments/tab.tpl

Tags: module, themes, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to show the product name on my-theme/modules/productcomments/tab.tpl but it works sometimes.

I don't know why but some products page show them and not others.

The code is simple. I have added {$product->name} but sometimes $product is null.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Modify [this line](https://github.com/PrestaShop/productcomments/blob/master/productcomments.php#L762) of code to this

```
$this->context->smarty->assign(array(
    'product' => $params['product'],
    'averageTotal' => round($average['grade']),
    'ratings' => ProductComment::getRatings($id_product),
    'nbComments' => (int) ProductComment::getCommentNumber($id_product),
));
```

and see if that fixes it.

I've noticed myself when I added related products list to product page that these variables get all screwed up ie. get replaced with another product's data, sometimes the `product` variable is null.

If this fixes it you might want to override productcomments module and fix the code in there otherwise on a module update your changes will be lost.

Comment: I tried to override the module class and changing directly on the module file. It doesn't work.